# react-native what does image!{imagename} mean?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I keep seeing the notion `require('image!my-icon');` and i am not sure what `image!` means exactly.
The docs don't provide info, and my thought is that it might not have to do with `react-native` specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require('image!my-icon');` is using legacy image loading. That means you already manually added image to your android or ios resource folder and trying to load it. This notation says JS packager do not try to manage this image.

Keep in mind `require('image!...')` **is deprecated and will be removed soon** (RN 0.39 or 0.40). In rare cases when you need direct access to native images you can use `nativeImageSource` from `Libraries/Image/`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**. As farwayer pointed out, the React Native packager doesn't use Webpack, so this answer is not correct.

This is Webpack's syntax for using a specific webpack loader for the file, see [loaders in `require`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#loaders-in-require). Basically, it tells Webpack to use the image-webpack-loader for this file.

Comment: The problem is react-native do not use webpack :) So you are wrong.

Comment: Dang, you're right. I thought that the React Native packager also uses Webpack in the background...