# Images don't render on device in react native

Tags: android, react-native, max

Images are stored in a folder inside my root folder:

```
-myProject
   - images
      - backgroundImage.png
      - logo.png
   - index.android.js
   - MainView.js
```

When I run the app on my device images simply won't show up. but the app runs as intended.

I refer to images like so:

```
var ListBackground = require('./images/table_bg.png');
.
.
class List extends Component {
.
.
 <Image source={ListBackground} style={styles.listBackground}>
.
.
}
```

Any idea why this happens? 
I saw something called webpack (sorry, new to JS) where they refer to images like `require('image!ListBackground');` which I could'nt find much online as to how to use this with `react-native`. 
ideas?

Comment: react native do not use webpack. Look here about `image!...` notation  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705936/react-native-what-does-imageimagename-mean/40716884#40716884

Answer (score 1):

A few things can be happening here: first, it might be that your image is not being found due to a path issue (although you should've gotten an error when running the code if that's the case). Another reason that come to mind is that you have not defined a width and height for your image (or something based on flex). Could you please post your styles declaration? The third reason is that images in Android are (or at least used to be) a bit tricky to work with in terms of dimensioning (I recall for instance having to set the width and height of an image through props instead of the style in order to make `borderRadius` work.

Comment: Also, you don't need to worry about webpack. The syntax that you're using to import the image is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
source={require('./images/table_bg.png')}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the code in the question. It makes no difference to initialize a variable to the value of `require` than to pass it directly.